# How can I pass a structure to a process created with fork & execv?

Tags: c++, ipc

My goal is first create a structure and fill it with bunch of data and pass *fork()* a new process from the parent and call *execv()* function to run the program that I want.While doing that I want to pass a structure to this child process with the second parameter of *execv()*, so is this possible ? if so, how can I do that ?

If I can't pass a structure, can I pass a memory address of variable, so that the program in the child process can access to the data in that address ?

I know I can use different IPC methods for doing such things, but I'm specifically interested with this kind of method if there is.

Comment: You could *serialize* the structure and pass as argument to the program you `exec`. But I would not recommend that. Instead think about some other [*inter-process communication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) primitive, like pipes or even plain files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks for you comment, but what do you mean by *serializing* ?

Comment: Put the structure in shared memory and let the exec'ed process access it in there. No need to serialise, since by definition, the other program has the same endianness, and presumably compiler and definition of the structure so there should be no compatibility issues.

Comment: @MarkSetchell as I stated in the question, "I know I can use different IPC methods for doing such things, but I'm specifically interested with this kind of method if there is."